# battery indicator is blank

Tags: drivers

Novice -

installed ubuntu LTS on acer laptop but the battery status does not appear to 'know' anything about my battery. Laptop charges fine etc but no info available?

Comment: Have you installed a new battery? This happened to me with my last computer after buying a replacement battery from e-bay.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that its set correct.  Try this, open System Settings, and click on power.  Once the windows opens, make sure it set to the first option "When battery is present"

[image]